# read data from .mdb files using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have .mdb file stored on to my local drive. I want to read the data from .mdb file and put into a csv file using powershell script.
As I am new to powershell, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can find many samples by searching. see pages like these. 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/08/13/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-query-a-microsoft-access-database-with-a-windows-powershell-script.aspx
http://www.gunnalag.com/2014/06/04/powershell-script-query-specified-columns-mdb-database/

Answer (score 1):

you should open [access db](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh855069.aspx) then convert to csv like this:

```
$db = Open-AccessDatabase -name phone.db -path %temp%/db/ 
Get-AccessData -sql "select * from table1" -connection $db | Export-Csv -Path %temp%/db/phone.csv –NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Looks like you copied this directly from here, but you didn't copy enough for it to be useful https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2009/11/27/export-access-data-to-csv-file/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the answer for 2015 and I mention Microsoft blog which includes a module for reading and writing. also Microsoft blog change in 2016 I think u can read the dates .  the GitHub link for 2018 . I'd like to know you are good with the date or not . second, I just said that code like that code.